Calling a Spring Controller that has a @RequestPart parameter of type HashMap<FilesUploadEnum, MultipartFile>
I have a Spring Controller for a service that uploads a variable number of files and I would like to send them all encapsulated in a HashMap<FilesUploadEnum, MultipartFile> object instead of one by one as @RequestPart-annotated MultipartFile parameters.
The elements of FilesUploadEnum are possible qualitative types for each file, for example:
public enum FilesUploadEnum {
    CUSTOMER_CONSENT,
    CUSTOMER_COMPLAINT,
    CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION
    ...;

The code for the Controller is:
@PostMapping(path = "/file",
             consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Void> saveFiles(
              @RequestPart(value = "attached_files")
              MultiValueMap<FilesUploadEnum, MultipartFile> files) { ...

My question is: can I use Postman to make a HTTP request that such a controller can accept? I included Content-Type: multipart/form-data as a Header, but I couldn't find a way of sending the attached_files part in the Body/form-data part of the request. I cannot just include the names of the files as keys and the corresponding files as values.
Or maybe I cannot make such a request with Postman and I have to use another Client app? Thanks in advance for any help I can get :) .

Just send a list or array of MultipartFile objects.

I don't understand the entity "FilesUploadEnum".
If it is the name of a given file, why not replace the input parameter with:
"@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> files"

and get the file names directly from the object like this:
files.forEach(f-> System.out.println(f.getOriginalFilename()));


and from postman send multiple files from tab "Body" => "form-date" => on key field You can find dropdown with Text/File (choose File) => name it "file" => send it

Thanks for your reply, I'll definitely try this approach. However, I just realized there was a misleading detail in my question: the values in the FilesUploadEnum enum are not the files' names, but qualitative types, for example CUSTOMER_CONSENT, CUSTOMER_COMPLAINT, etc. That's why I thought of a Map as the most fitting data structure here, because there's this label info associated with each file that I'd like to be part of the request. But maybe there's a way of including such a type label in the MultipartFile object itself? Anyways, I corrected the question.

You can try put that to the metadata of the file or append to filename or send map<FileName, FileType> in HttpHeader (be careful to non allowed chars) but imo all of that is stinky solution.
Maybe instead try to package files by type and then send that type as a header?
